# How would one use Pytorch's Autograd to backprop multiple layers (matracies)?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, backpropagation

Just in order to learn I'm trying to modify this three layer neural network from scratch to still use everything from scratch EXCEPT I want to use the Pytorch Autograd function to calculate the deltas and backprop the weights. Specifically I just want to take the mean squared error of the prediction minus y stored as 'loss' and do a 'loss.backwards()' on it.
I made a successful linear regression model with Autograd but it's not working here

I've tried putting the layers and the weights inside and outside the for loop. I've done tinkering with trying to get everything to 'require_grad'.
As is, this is my current error with Python3.6

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nn_scratch_trash.py", line 96, in <module>
    layer_2.data -= layer_2.grad.data
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'
```

The code...

```
import numpy as np
import random
import torch

np.random.seed(111)

X = np.random.randn(6,4)
y = np.random.randn(6,1)


def zeround(x):
    x = 1 / ( 1 + (np.exp(-x)))
    x = np.around(x)
    return x

# Create Random X and y arrays of random 1s and 0s with the zeround function I made.
y = zeround(y)
X = zeround(X)

X, y = V(X), V(y)

# randomly initialize our weights
weight_0 = V(np.random.randn(4,6), requires_grad=True) - 1
weight_1 = V(np.random.randn(6,7), requires_grad=True) - 1
weight_2 = V(np.random.randn(7,1), requires_grad=True) - 1

# Feed forward through layers 0, 1, and 2
layer_1 = V(((X @ weight_0)), requires_grad=True)
layer_2 = V(((layer_1 @ weight_1)), requires_grad=True)
layer_3 = V(((layer_2 @ weight_2)), requires_grad=True)

print((layer_1))
print((layer_2))
print((layer_3))
print(y)

for j in range(10000):
    # torch backprop
    loss = ((layer_3 - y))
    loss.backward()

    print(weight_2.requires_grad)

    # UPDATE WEIGHTS
    weight_0.data -= weight_0.grad.data
    weight_1.data -= weight_1.grad.data
    weight_2.data -= weight_2.grad.data

    weight_0.grad.data.zero_()
    weight_1.grad.data.zero_()
    weight_2.zero_()

    if j == 9999:
        print (loss.item())
```

Comment: What is `V` here?

Comment: and how are you doing `requires_grad = True` on numpy arrays?

Comment: 'V' makes Pytorch use it in some way I'm not well versed enough to properly explain. I tried adding requires_grad=True to the line with X, y = V(X), V(y). It gives a new error 'RuntimeError: grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs'